# How do I setup MongoDB on Heroku with MongoHQ and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, express

I have an application that runs locally, which is what I'm used to..

Heroku provided the following code snippet:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
  process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
  'mongodb://localhost/mydb';

mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
  db.collection('mydocs', function(er, collection) {
    collection.insert({'mykey': 'myvalue'}, {safe: true}, function(er,rs) {
    });
  });
});
```

And here's the code snippet from MongoHQ:

```
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGOHQ_URL, function(err, db) {
  // operate on the collection named "test"
  var collection = db.collection('test')
```

Here's my localHost code in Node.js/Express for MongoDB:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017,
                                                { 'native_parser' : true }));
var db = mongoclient.db('demo');


mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    if (err) throw err
    app.listen(9999);
    console.log("Express server started on port 9999");
});
```

How can I convert this codeset, or merge the two, or something..?

Answer (score 0):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
  process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
  'mongodb://localhost/demo';


var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoUri,
                                                { 'native_parser' : true }));

mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    if (err) throw err
    app.listen(9999);
    console.log("Express server started on port 9999");
});
```

Try that.